# Opacity css issue in IE 8 used in jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, opacity, master-pages

I designed this site for my friend: http://noorjamali.info/

I have one problems with this site - why do these lines not work in IE 8?

```
$j('#lveis-wrapper_3').animate({
    opacity: 0.0,
    height : 740
}, 1200, function () {
    // Animation complete.
)};
```

This is jQuery - so why does not work in IE 8?

What is the replacement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why cant you try http://jsfiddle.net/9FBrx/

```
$('#lveis-wrapper_3').animate({
                height : '300px',
opacity:'0'                  
            }, 1200, function () {
                // Animation complete.
})
```

Comment: Because he wants both animations at the same time. And BTW it is fadeOut or fadeTo(0)

Comment: @Chandu vkm was your mean fadeOut(1200); / i can not use it because by doing that my footer comes next to header / fadeOut(1200) = display : none / i am looking for visibility : hidden instead / so opacity can do this job / but it does not work on IE8...

Comment: @Chandu vkm thanks for update / your sample works perfect in IE 8 / so what is the problem about my codes?

Answer (score 0):

if your code is correct:-

there are some problem with IE compatibility
give this meta code

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Comment: you can do one thing you are using jquery... you can use addclass property...  for animate something

Comment: would you please give me an example!

Comment: $("div").css({"position":"absolute","color":"#fff"});  or ,,

Comment: $("p:last").addClass("selected highlight");

Comment: but there is no effect by using addClass!